# How to use FlutterTts (Text to speech)

Tags: flutter, text-to-speech

I'm creating an app and I want to use `FlutterTts` but when I try to create an instance it dosen't find the `import` for recongnizing. 
Here is what I tried https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_tts

Comment: What is your Exact Issue? You can also paste code and screenshot

Comment: I solved it. I used `import 'package:flutter_tts/flutter_tts.dart';` instead of `import 'package:Flutter_tts/Flutter_tts.dart';`. The difference was the Capital letter. Thanks

Comment: Ok good, next time please follow this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to know how to ask a good question